# C++ OpenGL weired ortographic camera

Tags: c++, opengl

I was trying to set OpenGL up for rendering 2D stuff.

```
int width = 640, height = 480;
void render() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    int w, h;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &w, &h);
    glOrtho(0.0, w, h, 0.0, -1.0, 10.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //RECTANGLE
    glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(0,0);
    glVertex2f(width, 0);
    glVertex2f(width, height);
    glVertex2f(0, height);
    glEnd();
}
```

When I now resize the window the Rectangle would change it's size (in pixels) and instead of keeping it's size of 640x480 it would get smaller, why does that happen?

As far as I understood [glOrtho](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) the `glOrtho(0.0, w, h, 0.0, -1.0, 10.0);` should setup an orthographic camera filling the window with the size of the window.

Hope for clarification. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not update your viewport transform. You should add this too:

```
int w, h;
glfwGetWindowSize(window, &w, &h);
glViewport(0, 0, w, h); // <------------ THIS
glOrtho(0.0, w, h, 0.0, -1.0, 10.0);
```

> As far as I understood glOrtho the glOrtho(0.0, w, h, 0.0, -1.0, 10.0); should setup an orthographic camera filling the window with the size of the window.

No. `glOrtho` sets up a camera so that (0,0) maps to the top-left corner and (w,h) to the bottom-right corner **of the viewport**. Since you did not change the viewport, the (width,height) now map somewhere inside the viewport rectangle, making your quad smaller.

Answer (score 0):

`glfwGetWindowSize()` doesn't retrieve the size of the window in pixels. From GLFW documentation:

> Do not pass the window size to glViewport or other pixel-based OpenGL calls. The window size is in screen coordinates, not pixels. Use the framebuffer size, which is in pixels, for pixel-based calls.

To get the framebuffer size, use `glfwGetFramebufferSize()`:

```
glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &w, &h);
```

Also, make sure to call `glViewport()` when the size of the window changes.